# Fill value in multiple cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

In MS Excel, after selecting a range of cells it is possible to enter a value and press CTRL+ENTER to have that value set in all selected cells.

Is there a keystroke in Google Spreadsheets that would achieve the same result?

*Note:* I know about the drag the cell's corner feature; I'm interested in doing this using only the keyboard.

Right now the closest to this I've got is:

- enter value in one cell
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>;
- select range of cells;
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

but I'd be a lot happier if it's possible to do this in fewer steps.

Comment: And anyhow, the 'drag the cell's corner feature' doesn't just copy values; it increments them, often undesirably.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This should be possible see: [Keyboard shortcuts for Google spreadsheets](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181110).

Are you using a Mac?

The workflow is as follows

1. Enter the value in one of the cells
2. Select your range with your cursor by grabbing from the first cell and dragging (no need to hold the blue cross in the corner, but the range should be highlighted when you are finished)
3. Type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (windows) <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Mac)

This fills the selected range with the value.

The only other option would be to use [Array formulas](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71291)

> When you press Ctrl+Shift+Enter while editing a formula, you'll automatically get =ArrayFormula( added to your formula.

Consider saving the [official shortcuts for Google Spreadsheet](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181110) as a bookmark on your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I finally realized why it wasn't working: I tried CTRL+ENTER while I was in edit mode in a cell (in Excel it works that way). In GDocs, after entering the value the cell must first be saved and then the keystroke works.

Comment: Oh man, this is a tremendous time saver. it recognizes the pattern you are trying to replicate for an entire column e.g. I am tracking NFL average scores in column B. Column E has total points scored, column D has games played. In cell B2 I can enter "=Divide(E2,D2)" then highlight all cells from B2 to B33 (32 NFL Teams)
Hold ctrl and enter. Voilà, the pattern is applied to all the cells for each team

Comment: So glad to have finally found the solution to this. I wonder why Google put in that extra step—it ends up requiring at least two extra keystrokes and generally feels clunky.

Comment: Adding on to what @CristianLupascu has posted for Windows, on MacOS, key in your value, hit `ENTER`, then `COMMAND` + `ENTER`

Comment: @phwd It seems to only duplicate the value of the first cell (the one on the top left): 1) enter the value "1" in the cell A2 2) click outside the cell to apply the edit (and quit the edit mode) 3)drag the cell A2 to A1 (its draws a selection containing A2+A2). 4) type `ctrl`+`enter` RESULT: it deletes the editing (A1 et A2 are empty)

Answer (score 13):

You can select multiple cells, type in your value, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to fill down, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to fill right.

Comment: This doesn't work in FireFox 37 under Mint 17.

Comment: Works in Chrome on OSX...

Comment: Also works in Chrome 73 under Mint 19. Perhaps this is a Chrome-only feature?

Comment: This doesn't work on Chrome in Windows. Ctrl+D is a browser bookmark shortcut, Google Sheets can't capture that.

Comment: @leetNightshade: Would you mind double-checking? Keyboard shortcuts are locale-dependent, and a lot of sites capture Ctrl+F and other keys. If Windows Chrome doesn't allow such keys to be captured, that's something I'd really like to know.

Comment: @MichaelScheper I double checked. Still the same, Ctrl+D is browser bookmark even on docs.google.com. Ctrl+F is captured, but not Ctrl+D.

Answer (score 1):

I found this worked for me as long as the cells were adjacent. There is one step you need to add after entering your value in the first cell...

> You can select multiple cells, type in your value and hit
> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to fill down,
> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to fill right.

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to complete (without re-selecting the range!) what is a useful single keystroke in Excel, with just two extra keystrokes in Sheets:

In Mac Sheets:

Select range (within a column), type value... <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Select range (within a row), type value... <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

In Mac Excel:

Select range (any range), type value... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>